# How to insert Bulk data to database using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I am working on microservice, I have to store 100000 data in 30s how to achieve this ?
If time exceedes it leads gateway timeout, then how can i handle the transaction?
Can any one help me out?

Comment: Can you tell me from where you are getting this records ? Are you reading from file or you are getting them via rest API or reading from another DB?

Comment: Do it asynchronously. Ideally, this microservice should immediately respond with a message conveying processing has started and it should trigger another backend process which will save the data (or save the data itself as a background process). After data is saved, you need to think of notification mechanism which informs the the original client of success or failure of data save (this could be an email or a message on a queue, etc.)

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary i am getting these records from the file

Comment: If you are sending file via REST api and then processing it, then you need to follow what @Smile mentioned. Use Async mechanism to process the file.

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary  if time exceedes how can i handle transaction should I need to roolback transaction, how can I show the response to clint that transaction was not completed when gateway time out

Comment: @Smile is it required batch processing?

Comment: @SUMANSAJJID Your application will never know that gateway has timed out. Even if you keep a constant in your app code having the gateway timeout value, you will have to start rollbacking the transaction when x% of timeout time has elapsed. What if you are not able to rollback by that time? Client will never know what happened to transaction. Either reduce number of records or go via asynchronous route. Asynchronous way would need to you to rethink overall design but it would be a cleaner way. You can use batch processing or any other way to process the records.

Comment: @Smile thank you for your Valueable information.

Comment: @suman sajjid Batch processing also don't process 100k records in less than 30sec. You need to keep you processing asynchronous only. It means keep you file processing and send response that file is under process.

Comment: @Jayesh Choudhary if we send response file is under process then how can we send confirmation successful or unsuccessful?

Comment: Well that entirely depends upon kind of application you are having. Maybe you can send notification inside application or you notify via mail or text.

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary ok thank you, it will be helpful for me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.